# asp.net literal control bgcolor

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

How can I change the `bgcolor` and `font` of my `asp:Literal` control?

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 12):

Literal control means it doesn't output any surrounding tags. So include whatever tags you want in the .Text property of it and mark them appropriately.

E.g.

```
ltlFoo.Text = "<font style='background : orange;'>hello</font>";
```

Answer (score 8):

Silky is totally right, but please, please for my sanity, use CSS instead of inline styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .beautiful
    {
         font-family: Georgia, serif;
         color: #369;
    }
</style>

<asp:Literal ID="myLitControl" runat="server" Text="<div class='beautiful'>Some Beautiful Text</div>" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Literal controls only output exactly what you put in them, nothing else.

Label controls do the same but wrap them in a span which you could do apply a style to.  Change your Literal to a Label and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

In simple `asp:Literal` is a style less control, so enclose this with another element like div or span and give style to this element.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this

```
<div style="color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)">
                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"  ></asp:Literal>
```

you can create a CSS class then put it inside a DIV